# adding new zshell command line custom git completions

Tags: git, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I installed git via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)). I get command line completions via the script installed in

```
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/
```

However I want my custom git-* scripts to be completed too.

How would I tack this on to existing git completions?

Comment: For example which command? It should work by default.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a couple of examples.

- Adding completion for an alias

If you have an alias for pull like this one:

```
alias gp='git push'
```

then you can define the alias to use the same completion as `git-push` by doing.

```
compdef _git gp=git-push
```

- Adding completion for a new command

This is a tougher one. Writing completion scripts for *zsh* is not trivial, you can take a look at the ones [in this project](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions) for some guidance. For example, take a look at the [completion script](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_git-wtf) for [git-wtf](https://github.com/michaelklishin/git-wtf)

- Reuse existing completion, but modified

If you have a script to search in the log like this:

```
query="$1"
shift
git log -S"$query" "$@"
```

You want to use the copmletion of `git-log`, with a small modification: You want to complete first for a search string and then use the usual options for `git-log`. Then you can use this:

```
_git-search () {
if (( CURRENT == 2 )); then
    _message "search string"
    return
fi

CURRENT=$(( $CURRENT - 1 ))
_git-log
}

_git-search "$@"
```

EDIT: Also, to actually use your newly defined completion files, you have to add the directory where they are stored to the `fpath`